# 404 Page is Appending Home Page

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, templates, 404, error-pages

We have created a template called /site/404. The site is working correctly as far as pulling articles, and content properly for all of our different URLs.

When we go to either a template that does not exist, or a URL segment that is beyond the scope of an entry, our 404 page is showing up. However, also appended to it is the home page at the bottom. When logged in either as an "Super Admin" or when debugging is enabled, we get a PHP error below the 404 page, then the home page is appended.

[image: PHP Error on 404 Page]

In the admin, we've updated our Global Template preferences as the following:

[image: Global Template Preferences Settings]

We are using Rob Sanchez's Resource Router (https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router) to allow multiple URLs to use the same template without resorting to EE's pages module. I've gone through and disabled that, as well as all of the modules to see if that would fix the issue, and it hasn't.

I'm on EE2.9, but upgraded from 2.8. Again, things are working well with everything but our 404 page. We were having the same issue on 2.8 as well.

Here is our .HTACCESS file, just so that we can alleviate that. Its been copied form Ellis Lab's official support page. https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

```
ErrorDocument 404 /site/404

RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|ttf|woff) [NC]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If we remove all of our code in the home page template, our PHP error stays, but obviously the appended home page goes away. We also then don't have a home page.

Similarly, if we remove all of the code in our 404 template, the 404 page goes away, but the PHP error stays at the top and the home page content is shown.

Our 404 template is as follows:

```
{embed="_includes/header" entry_title="Page Not Found" body_class=""}

<div class="main-content" role="main">
        <div class="panel masthead">
            <section>
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
                    </hgroup>
                    <img src="/img/masthead-images/cadillac-margarita.jpg" alt="Cadillac margarita">
            </section>
        </div>

        <div class="panel error-message">
            <section>
                <h2>Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for.</h2>
                <p>The page could have been moved, or you may have entered the address or link incorrectly.</p>

                <div class="btn primary medium"><a href="/">GO TO OUR HOME PAGE</a></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

{embed="_includes/footer"}
```

Any suggestions in this area would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, Javier. Have you tried a) turning off your extensions b) use a non-arbitrary template for the 404 (anything) and checked your template route manager settings?

Comment: A. I have tried to disable extensions and modules with no affect.

B. I have also tried using only

     "404"

as my error template code, without any resolve.

Segments aren't required on any of my templates in the route manager.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I never did find a solution to this. I installed a brand new version of EE 2.9 into a new database and minimally configured it. When I went to a page that didn't exist to instantiate the 404 page, I found the same issue.